# Infinite scroll issue when footer occurs

Tags: php, ajax

I require the infinite scroll to occur when the scroller reaches the footer and not the end of the document. I have used the snippet in this way

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
    if($(window).scrollTop()==$(document).height()-$(window).height())
    {
        load++;
        if(load*ippage>nbr)
        {
            $(".loader").hide();    
        }
        else
        {               
            $.ajax({
                url: "fetch_array.php",
                type: "POST",
                data:{"load":load,"item_per_page":ippage,"typeno":category},
                dataType: "html",
                success: function(result)
                {
                    var results = $.parseJSON(result);
                    var dataCount=results["displayCount"]+8;
                    if(results["displayCount"]!=0)
                    {
                        scrollDisplayContent(category,results['productResults'],dataCount);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }

});
```

And for reaching the footer i just tried in this way

```
var footer=$(footer).height();
$(window).scroll(function(){
    if($(window).scrollTop()==($(document).height()-$(window).height()-footer))
    {
        load++;
        if(load*ippage>nbr)
        {
            $(".loader").hide();    
        }
        else
        {               
            $.ajax({
                url: "fetch_array.php",
                type: "POST",
                data:{"load":load,"item_per_page":ippage,"typeno":category},
                dataType: "html",
                success: function(result)
                {
                    var results = $.parseJSON(result);
                    var dataCount=results["displayCount"]+8;
                    if(results["displayCount"]!=0)
                    {
                        scrollDisplayContent(category,results['productResults'],dataCount);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }
});
```

but it doesn't work fine Can anyone please help me regarding this

Comment: What exactly is the problem? Do you see an AJAX request in the developer tools? I would try to debug with breakpoints etc. Does the footer variable hold the pixel number you'd expect (maybe you're measuring it to early)?

Comment: What i need is to get the datas loaded when the scroller reaches the footer start point. But what is happening is even after the scroller reaches the footer start point the datas not getting loaded and it is loaded only when the scroller reaches the document end

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi Deepak try this which is help to your query.

```
screen_size=$(document).height();

var footer=$(footer).height();

scroll_limit=parseInt(screen_size)-footer;


$(document).on("scroll",function(){

  cur_size=$(document).scrollTop();

  if(parseInt(cur_size) > parseInt(scroll_limit)){
     console.log(3);
    //put here your ajax function
  }
  else{
       console.log(1);
  }

});
```